# Python Google Geocoding API - IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, google-maps, csv, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I'm working on a personal project visualizing location data, and here I reverse geocode location data from Google through the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#reverse-example), by feeding it coordinates and retrieving a City Name and Country.

It's a CSV file, with 2 columns: "Location" (Latitude and Longitude) and "Time" (Date+Time). There are 8533 rows.

Sample Data:

```
    Location                Time
--------------------------------------------------
| 41.2911084,2.0779035 | 4/15/2015 10:58         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 41.2885014,2.0725591 | 4/15/2015 10:07         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 41.3484125,2.1442487 | 4/15/2015 9:56          |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I'm having a problem with the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#reverse-example) where I keep getting an error. Let me show the code, first.

```
# import necessary modules
import pandas as pd
import json, requests, logging

# configure logging for our tool
lfh = logging.FileHandler('reverseGeocoder.log')
lfh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s'))
log = logging.getLogger('reverseGeocoder')
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(lfh)

# load the gps coordinate data
df = pd.read_csv('LocationHistory.csv')

# create new columns
df['geocode_data'] = ''
df['city'] = ''
df['country'] = ''


df.head()

# function that handles the geocoding requests
def reverseGeocode(latlng):

    result = {}
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={0}&key={1}'
    apikey = 'API_KEY_GOES_HERE'

    request = url.format(latlng, apikey)
    log.info(request)
    data = json.loads(requests.get(request).text)
    log.info(data)
    result = data['results'][0]['address_components']
    return {
        'city': result[3]['long_name'],
        'country': result[6]['long_name']
    }

# comment out the following line of code to geocode the entire dataframe
#df = df.head()

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # for each row in the dataframe, geocode the lat-long data
    revGeocode = reverseGeocode(df['Location'][i])
    df['geocode_data'][i] = revGeocode
    df['city'] = revGeocode['city']
    df['country'] = revGeocode['country']


    # once every 100 loops print a counter
    #if i % 100 == 0: 
    print i

df.head()

df.to_csv('LocationHistory2.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

The error in question that I keep receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...\ReverseGeocoding.py", line 45, in <module>
    revGeocode = reverseGeocode(df['Location'][i])
  File "D:\...\ReverseGeocoding.py", line 37, in reverseGeocode
    'country': result[6]['long_name']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think that part of the problem is that I need a check in place, in-case the API doesn't return anything for the locations. Why it wouldn't return anything, I have no idea.

I'm quite new to the world of APIs (and Python), but how could I get this code to a running state?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to run a check on the types key for the address attribute you want. So try something like;

```
    result = data['results'][0]['address_components']
    city = ''
    country = ''

    for item in result:
        if 'administrative_area_level_1' in item[types]:
            city = item['long_name']
        elif 'country' in item[types]:
            country = item['long_name']
    return {
        'city': city,
        'country': country
    }
```

Comment: this worked for me. just changed `item[type]` to `item['type']`

Answer (score 1):

> I think that part of the problem is that I need a check in place,
>   in-case the API doesn't return anything for the locations.

Indeed. The first thing you want to do is to put your `requests` call in a try/except block to catch [possible exceptions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions) during the request phase (and there are quite a few things that can go wrong when doing an HTTP request).

BTW you don't have to build the querystring manually - `requests` [takes care of it](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) in a safer way (escaping etc), and you'll still have access to the resulting url in the `response` object if you want it. So as a starter you want:

```
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
apikey = 'API_KEY_GOES_HERE'
try:
    response = requests.get(url, params={"key":apikey, "latlng":latlng})
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    # this will log the whole traceback
    logger.exception("call failed with %s", e)
    # here you either re-raise the exception, raise your own exception,
    # or return anything
    return None
```

Now you also want to check the [response's status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) - anything else than 200 means you don't have your data

```
if response.status_code != 200:
    logger.error("got status code %s", response.status_code)
    # idem, either raise your own exception or
    # return anything
    return None
```

FWIW, `response` has a [`raise_for_status()` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) that will raise a RequestException if you get a 4XX or 5XX response, so you can simplify the whole thing to:

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url, params={"key":apikey, "latlng":latlng})
    response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    # this will log the whole traceback
    logger.exception("call failed with %s", e)
    # here you either re-raise the exception, raise your own exception,
    # or return anything
    return None
```

Now you can expect you do have a valid response, so let's get our json data. Here again, `requests` already provides a shortcut. Note that if your response's content type is not 'application/json' or the response's content is invalid json, you'll get a `ValueError` but well, I think we can trust google to do the job here ;)

```
data = response.json()
```

I don't remember exactly the whole geocoding API so should really double-check the doc but IIRC as long as you got a 200, you *should* have some valid data.

"Why it wouldn't return anything, I have no idea."

Connection lost, API limits, server down (yes it happens), there are a lot of possible reasons. With the above code you should at least get a hint.

Now you may still not have all you expect in the resulting data - here again, check the docs, manually replay the requests for geoloc that failed and inspect the response and data etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I keep getting indentation errors when I try to put the try/except block within the reverseGeocode() beneath the apikey. It should work, but keeps saying `unexpected indent`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Edit: Fixed that, but keep getting my previous error.